# photo upload options to facebook in node.js

Tags: javascript, facebook, node.js, flickr, picasa

I am building a site with nodejs and mongodb and using facebook for authentication..
my users will be required to **upload certain photo and others will be able to view them**.

Since I am using facebook, I am wondering if I should allow users to **upload their photos to their facebook profile and I'll save the links** into the database so that later on other users can view this.

Is this the right approach ? 
or **should I use flickr or picasa or something else ?**

I have to do this in javascript and I know facebook has support for this.

Please let me know what you think.

EDIT:

Hi,

Finally I found the module **connect-form** to upload the file to the server and then uploading the file to facebook using the module **facebook-js**.
I found fb.api for "/me/feed" works perfectly in node.js server.
But when I tried to use the graph api for "/me/photos" as mentioned in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/album/, I got the error. That is because it expects the source to be in "multipart/form-data". 
In my html, it is already "multipart/form-data", otherwise I'll not 
get the file in the server side. 
 
In the server side, however, I am not very sure about how to embed 
this in FB.api... what should be the "source" parameter in FB.api "/me/ 
photos" ? I tried this with "source:files.source" as mentioned in my 
example. But it does not work. may be i am missing something very 
silly...

```
app.post('/', function(req, res, next){

  req.form.complete(function(err, fields, files){
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {

      fb.apiCall('POST', '/me/photos',
        {access_token: fields.access_token, message: fields.message, source:files.source},
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) {
                console.log('Error in facebook Photo UPLOAD', error);
                return;
            }
          console.log('facebook RESPONSE :', response);
          console.log('facebook BODY :', body);
          res.redirect('back');
          //res.render('done', {body: body});
        }
      );

    }
  });
```

Comment: Obviously you can use Facebook for this purpose. **P.S.**: I don't think you can *upload photos* using Javascript.

Comment: well i am referring to this - http://www.webdevhub.net/facebook-api/picture-upload-facebook-api and looks like it's possible.

Comment: Here you are submitting to Facebook end-point directly! The example described in the article is **NOT** recommended as it'll move your visitors away from your website/app!

Comment: you are right. in fact, I just realized that this is not the right approach... would you suggest something better ? or will it solve my problem if i use ajax submit ?

Comment: since I am using socket.io in node.js, I can certainly send these information to the server and process it there.. Please suggest if there is a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to upload photos to Facebook using the url, read the following article:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/526/

I suggest to use some CDN for photos like Amazon S3 which is very reliable and scalable. Then you can optionally have it on Facebook too with a simple API call (don't forget about extended permissions to upload photos in this case)

hope this helps